# Markdown library that supports subset restriction?

Tags: markdown

For example, Stack Overflow allows only a very small subset of Markdown syntax [in comment editor](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

I'd like to know if there is any open source Markdown library that supports syntax restriction? I'm currently using Python but I can't even find one in any language.

Comment: What syntax do you want to disallow?

Comment: For example, disable HTML so that commenters won't mess up my blog. Also disable heading tags, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used any Python Markdown parsers, but I have used a Java Markdown library called [Pegdown](https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown) that allows you to enable or disable various syntax extentions.

For example, this snippet enables [Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/) [table syntax](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/#table) and disables both inline HTML and HTML blocks in the markdown input:

```
PegDownProcessor processor 
        = new PegDownProcessor(Parser.TABLES | Parser.SUPPRESS_ALL_HTML);
String html = processor.markdownToHtml(markdown);
```

[Here](http://www.decodified.com/pegdown/api/org/pegdown/Extensions.html) is a list of all available PegDown extensions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a C library called [peg-markdown](http://github.com/jgm/peg-markdown). The markdown syntax is defined as a grammar, so it is fairly easy to modify. To only allow a subset of markdown, you can remove the sections that match against the offending syntax so they won't be converted to tokens.

There are Ruby bindings for peg-markdown, but I suppose it should not be difficult to write bindings for Python.